# Spark using python: How to resolve Stage x contains a task of very large size (xxx KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I've just created python list of `range(1,100000)`.

Using SparkContext done the following steps:

```
a = sc.parallelize([i for i in range(1, 100000)])
b = sc.parallelize([i for i in range(1, 100000)])

c = a.zip(b)

>>> [(1, 1), (2, 2), -----]

sum  = sc.accumulator(0)

c.foreach(lambda (x, y): life.add((y-x)))
```

Which gives warning as follows:

**ARN TaskSetManager: Stage 3 contains a task of very large size (4644 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.**

How to resolve this warning? Is there any way to handle size? And also, will it affect the time complexity on big data?

Comment: First of all what exactly is `life`? Did you mean `sum` accumulator? Either way it shouldn't be a problem here. See [this](http://mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201407.mbox/%3CCAJgQjQ_87xkpACXFpoOn0iuLZ2Q00qwWTLHmZfy9BAhKqDkv0A@mail.gmail.com%3E) for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding @leo9r comment: consider using not a python `range`, but `sc.range` https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.range.

Thus you avoid transfer of huge list from your driver to executors.

Of course, such RDDs are usually used for testing purposes only, so you do not want them to be broadcasted.

Comment: using `sc.range` instead of `range` works in the toy example, but misses the more general problem (how data is communicated between python and java)

Answer (score 19):

The general idea is that PySpark creates as many java processes than there are executors, and then ships data to each process. If there are too few processes, a memory bottleneck happens on the java heap space.

In your case, the specific error is that the RDD that you created with `sc.parallelize([...])` did not specify the number of partition (argument `numSlices`, see the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=parallelize#pyspark.SparkContext.parallelize)). And the RDD defaults to a number of partition that is too small (possibly it is constituted by a single partition).

To solve this problem, simply specify the number of partitions wanted:

```
a = sc.parallelize([...], numSlices=1000)   # and likewise for b
```

As you specify higher and higher number of slices, you will see a decrease in the size stated in the warning message. Increase the number of slices until you get no more warning message. For example, getting

```
Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (696 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB
```

means that you need to specify more slices.

---

Another tip that may be useful when dealing with memory issues (but this is unrelated to the warning message): by default, the memory available to each executor is 1 GB or so. You can specify larger amounts through the commandline, for example with `--executor-memory 64G`.

Comment: How can I determine the best number of slices to use? From your example it seems that 7 is need to keep each under 100 KB. Although how do I determine what the size of the task is?

Comment: @user2361174 As you wrote, you will know if the size is too high through the warning message (`blabla contains a task of very large size`..) - I don't know any other way to get this info before trying.

Comment: If you `import sys, math` then `n = math.ceil(sys.getsizeof(your_list) / 102400)` will be the minimum number of slices to keep all of them under 100KB

Answer (score 15):

Spark natively ships a copy of each variable over during the shipping of the task. For large sizes of such variables you may want to use [Broadcast Variables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables)

If you are still facing size problems, Then perhaps this data should be an RDD in itself

Comment: Hi @Hitesh Dharamdasani, Is there any way to change the SPARK configuration files to maximize the task size.?

Comment: Sorry I am late. 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/tuning.html has some recommendations under the "Data Serialization" section. but its generally not recommended. I have had some success with the kyro serializer but not something to boast about. Broadcast variables are better

Comment: what to do if the variable is not serialisable (and thus you'll have to use operators like `mapPartitions`)? I don't think it can be wrapped inside a broadcast variable.

Comment: Just to clarify this answer a bit more. The variable that is going over 100 KB in the provided example is `[i for i in range(1, 100000)]`