# increase task size spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I got a problem when I execute my code in spark-shell.

```
[Stage 1:>             (0 + 0) / 16]
17/01/13 06:09:24 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 1 contains a task of very large size (1057 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
[Stage 1:>             (0 + 4) / 16]
```

After this warning the execution blocked.

Who can I solve it?

I tried this but it's doesn't solve the problem.

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("MyApp")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "3g")
    .set("spark.executor.memory" ,"3g");
val sc = new SparkContext(conf);`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's most likely because of large size requirements by the variables in any of your tasks.
The accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878654/spark-using-python-how-to-resolve-stage-x-contains-a-task-of-very-large-size-x) should help you.

Comment: Yeah l read this post but I don't understand how to use it. Can you give me an example plz

Comment: When I try I have a error like cartesian is not member of  broadcast

Comment: For that, either create a new question(preferable) or post your code and update your question. Also please accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 8):

I had similar error:

```
scheduler.TaskSetManager: Stage 2 contains a task of very large size
(34564 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB
```

My input data was of size ~150MB with 4 partitions (i.e., each partition was of size ~30MB). That explains `34564 KB` size mentioned in above error message.

**Reason:**
Task is the smallest unit of work in spark that acts on partitions of your input data. Hence, if spark tells that task's size is more than recommended size, it means that the partition its handling has way too much data.

**Solution that worked for me:**

```
reducing task size => reduce the data its handling => increase
numPartitions to break down data into smaller chunks
```

- So, I tried increasing number of partitions and got rid of the error.
- One can check number of partitions in dataframe via `df.rdd.getNumPartitions`
- To increase partitions: `df.repartition(100)`

Comment: Learned a lot from this answer