# Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am reading data from a file into R dataframe. The dimension of the dataframe is 1788228 10. As this is huge, when I try to convert into SparkDataFrame, I get this warning:

> WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (48092 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.

and when I try to perform any action operation, like

> dim(df)

it gives me the below error

> Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

From other posts like [Spark using python: How to resolve Stage x contains a task of very large size (xxx KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878654/spark-using-python-how-to-resolve-stage-x-contains-a-task-of-very-large-size-x), I could understand that its happening because dataframe is very big in size. But how do I reduce the size? The post also suggest broadcasting. How do we do it using R? Help.

Comment: Which function are you using to upload your dataframe to Spark?

Comment: @j df = as.DataFrame(rdf)

Comment: If you want to upload a data frame to spark and play with it, you can also use sparklyr  (http://spark.rstudio.com/). Once installed, and connected to the cluster with something like this `sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")` you can upload your data to spark using `your_table_ref <- copy_to(sc, df)`. It's a different way to do it, but it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Java memory issues are a nightmare. Make sure you `rm()` as much from the working space and `gc()` often, write it at the end of a loop to clear on each iteration if you can!

And, try reading the data in from the frame line, by line and save it into the spark data frame.

here is a tutorial on reading it in incrementally:

[read line by line](https://www.r-bloggers.com/read-line-by-line-of-a-file-in-r/)

You are on your own with the spark part.