# Convert distinct values in a Dataframe in Pyspark to a list

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to get the distinct values of a column in a dataframe in Pyspark, to them save them in a list, at the moment the list contains "Row(no_children=0)"
but I need only the value as I will use it for another part of my code.

So, ideally only all_values=[0,1,2,3,4]

```
all_values=sorted(list(df1.select('no_children').distinct().collect()))
all_values


[Row(no_children=0),
 Row(no_children=1),
 Row(no_children=2),
 Row(no_children=3),
 Row(no_children=4)]
```

This takes around 15secs to run, is that normal?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use collect_set from functions module to get a column's distinct values.Here,

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df1.show()
+-----------+
|no_children|
+-----------+
|          0|
|          3|
|          2|
|          4|
|          1|
|          4|
+-----------+

>>> df1.select(F.collect_set('no_children').alias('no_children')).first()['no_children']
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Fantastic, this option is quicker.   Although the command line prints WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 849 contains a task of very large size (165 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.

Comment: This usually occurs either when huge list transferred from driver to executor or due to partitioning of data. Pls check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878654/spark-using-python-how-to-resolve-stage-x-contains-a-task-of-very-large-size-x

Comment: Anyways, hope this answer helped you. If you are fine with it, can you accept it.

Comment: how can i accept? I had seen that post but didn't really understand what to do, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to get only the values

```
list = [r.no_children for r in all_values]

list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
all_values = df1.select('no_children').distinct().rdd.flatMap(list).collect()
```