# Spark very large task warning

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I get warnings like this a lot in SparkSQL. What is this warning telling me, and do I need to care about this?

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 1186 contains a task of very large size (4691 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark using python: How to resolve Stage x contains a task of very large size (xxx KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878654/spark-using-python-how-to-resolve-stage-x-contains-a-task-of-very-large-size-x)

Answer (score -12, accepted):

This link will help you out:-
[Spark using python: How to resolve Stage x contains a task of very large size (xxx KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878654/spark-using-python-how-to-resolve-stage-x-contains-a-task-of-very-large-size-x?rq=1)

Please go once on the internet before asking any question here